# React-native-SQLite-storage : Not working with android version 10+

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-sqlite-storage

"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.66.4",
"react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1",

Have added below code in react-native.config.js file

```
module.exports = {
    dependencies: {
        "react-native-sqlite-storage": {
            platforms: {
                android: {
                    sourceDir:
                        "../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android-native",
                    packageImportPath: "import io.liteglue.SQLitePluginPackage;",
                    packageInstance: "new SQLitePluginPackage()"
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

Getting bulk update query issue
If i remove react-native.config code than it's working properly in android version 11 and above but if i add than it's working in
android version 10 and below

Everything is same than why it's giving query issue.

**Update query**

INSERT INTO Maintable SELECT * FROM Landingtable WHERE TRUE ON CONFLICT(Symbol) DO UPDATE SET Name = excluded.Name, Symbol = excluded.Symbol

Please help me to resolve this issue..